# Skipping certain lines of data - Python

Tags: python, list, csv, indexing

I have a CSV file with a ton of data that needs to be plotted and sorted and what not. An example of the data is below.

```
10, 50, 60, 74, 19
10, 55, 68, 93, 10
10, 84, 92, 75, 32
10, 58, 39, 82, 12
20, 15, 12, 84, 35
20, 53, 13, 96, 57
20, 53, 32, 64, 67
20, 56, 31, 29, 18
30, 85, 92, 18, 95
30, 75, 12, 92, 12
...
90, 35, 21, 95, 47
100, 67, 96, 73, 47
100, 86, 32, 62, 32
100, 32, 53, 69, 57
100, 34, 64, 72, 34
```

What I'm looking for is taking the first row, 4th, row, and 8th row, etc. and putting them into a list. so it looks as such:

```
column1 = ['10', '20', '30', ..., '100']
column3 = ['60', '12', '92', ..., '73']
column5 = ['19', '35', '95', ..., '47']
```

Note: the first row from the data set should be in the first column of the output, 2nd row from the data is the 2nd column of output, etc.
Also, I want to be able to control which columns I select to put into the lists (and which rows as well).

I'm also looking for a way to adjust which nth row I want to begin with. For example, if we start with row 2, the output would be as such:

```
column1 = ['10', '20', '30', ..., '100']
column3 = ['68', '13', '12', ..., '32']
column5 = ['10', '35', '12', ..., '32']
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

column1 = []
column2 = []
column4 = []

with open('csvFile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    w = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
    for i, line in enumerate(w):
        if i == 0 or i == 1:
            pass # Skip first row
        else:
            column1.append(line[1])
            column2.append(line[2])
            column4.append(line[4])
```

This gives me ALL the values in the columns, which I don't want. Maybe I'm overthinking this, as what I was thinking about doing after was indexing the lists and removing the values I don't want (which my dataset is MUCH larger than what is shown here - I have a total of 26 rows per first number (i.e. 26 rows of the number 10 with data after it, 26 rows of 20 with data, 26 of 30, etc.))

Comment: I'm so confused about the first row, 4th row, 8th row thing. It seems like 1st column, 3rd column and 5th column?

Comment: I'm looking for data once every 4 rows. So for example, if we start with the 2nd row (10, 55, 68, 93, 10), we would go the 6th row (20, 53, 13, 96, 57), 10th row (not displayed in the example). I also need to control which row I want to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check whether `i` is a multiple of four or not. If it is not a multiple of four then skip

```
with open("data", 'rb') as f:
    w = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ",")
    for i, line in enumerate(w):
        if (i % 4 == 0): 
            column1.append(line[0])
            column2.append(line[1])
            column3.append(line[2])
```

Comment: Why not `if (i % 4 == 0): #append lines` rather than test whether `if (i % 4 != 0):` and then pass and use the `else` branch?

Comment: because I'm groggy and didn't think of that :)

Comment: Ok, makes sense now that I look at it. Why I didn't think of this before I don't know. But now how would I go about actually controlling which row I begin with?

Comment: @BrandonMolyneaux it depends on what you mean by beginning. If you mean you want to start with the second row, and then every four from there you can change the test to be `i % 4 == 1`